# Import existing vpc, sg and rules to terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-import

Requirement - To import existing architecture to terraform cloud so that everything (create, update, delete) can be managed from terraform.

Issue: when I am importing SG group it's importing rules within that as well but I am not able to delete a single rule of the security group,

Similarly if I am importing sg rule I am not able to delete sg group.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Can you add the code you have along with the import commands you are using to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can import vpc, sg & sg rules all of them manually and then try to edit/update the sg /sg rule

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).